# Есть ли другие способы сделать элементы строчными, кроме display: inline?

Tags: html, css

Есть страница, на которую выводится список новостей.
Ссылка должна "прилипать" к тексту.

Структура следующая: контейнер из параграфов, в который  автоматически прогружается текст новости - это может быть параграф, список, див и тд.

Есть ли еще варианты сделать так, чтобы ссылка прилипала к тексту, кроме варианта с `display inline` и перечисления всех возможных элементов?

```css
.text_container {
  display: inline;
  p,
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5,
  h6 {
    display: inline;
  }
  ol,
  ul,
  div {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ol,
  div,
  ul+a {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}


}
```

```html
<p class="text_container">
      <p>Текст новости</p>
</p>
<a>Читать дальше</a>
```

Гуглила - не нашла. Возможно, плохо гуглила. Возможно, вопрос глупый.

Comment: вообще нельзя вкладывать абзац в абзац

Comment: окей, но это ситуация, в которой нельзя менять html, и нужно решить вопрос методами css

Comment: `display: inline-block;` + `line-height: ...px`

Comment: это ситуация, в которой **нужно** менять html. Потому что браузер разбивает твою разметку на три абзаца

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можете обернуть ваш код в `div` и задать `display: flex`

```css
div{
display: flex;
justify-content:flex-start;
align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p class="text_container">
      <p>Текст новости</p>
</p>
<a>Читать дальше</a>
</div>
```